# How can I use something like Auth0 when my front-end and back-end are separate?

Tags: java, keycloak, auth0, micronaut

I have been working on an app where the front-end (React) and back-end (Micronaut) are separate. They currently communicate via REST use Micronaut's built-in JWT authentication. I'd like to use something like Auth0 or Keycloak to avoid having to implement user management code.

Is that possible given the separation of my front-end and back-end? If so, are there any resources I can use? I haven't found many concrete answers to that question, but have been looking into OAuth's [Client Credentials Flow](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-oauth2-client-credentials-auth0-maven-java.html). Is that what I want in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auth0 has documentation on how to do authentication through their [authentication code flow](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#get-token) which can work well for REST APIs. It uses jwts, but gives you an easy way to verify the jwts and get the token info using their [get user info](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#get-user-info) api.

If this is not what you’re looking for, I would recommend checking out the [Auth0 authentication API docs](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#introduction). It walks you through setting up many different kinds of complex authentication flows and (in my opinion) makes them pretty easy to implement. Hope that helps!